# Express with Pug, How to add image in email(Not as attachment but as part of message content)

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I want to send an image in the email as part of body and not as attachement.  i have image in my template and does not appear when i send the email. i am new to this stuff, any body have an idea?? [image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your users open up the email in their email client it needs to make a HTTP request in order to get your image and display it in the body using your `<img>` tag. Given that your image is not an attachment you need to serve the image from a publicly accessible address such as an AWS S3 bucket or Azure Blob storage or whatever web hosting you are using. Update like so:

```js
img(src='https://my-domian.com/img/checking.png' alt='Your image description')
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. but i solved it earlier by this approach before you replied. Thanks for the update.

Comment: @Milanjotva thanks for confirming it worked and glad to hear you had already solved it! It can be a common issue with pug so I'm up-voting the question to make sure others can find it easier. Good luck with your project.